# AppleScript: How to write to a specific line of a text file?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

Sample contents of a .txt file on my Mac:

```
This is sentence A.
This is sentence B.
This is sentence C.
This is sentence D.
This is sentence E.
```

I want to implement a subroutine, like this:

```
writeTextAtSpecificLine(("This is the newcomer sentence." & linefeed), 4)
```

so that, the text file would consequently look like this:

```
This is sentence A.
This is sentence B.
This is sentence C.
This is the newcomer sentence
This is sentence D.
This is sentence E.
```

---

I know that I can accomplish my desired result by making each line of the text file its own item in an AppleScript `list` object, like so:

```
set theIndividualLinesOfTextFileAsList to paragraphs of (read theFilepathOfTxtFile)
```

I could then split the `list`, based on the desired line number, and then add it all back together.

But, does a more efficient method exist?

My real .txt file is much longer than the sample content above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited version:

```
set selected_file to ((path to documents folder as text) & "hom.txt") as alias
set text_data to "This is the newcomer sentence."

InsertLine(selected_file, text_data, 4)

on InsertLine(the_file, the_data, num_line)
    try
        set file_id to open for access the_file with write permission
        set text_data to read file_id

        -- CHECK EMPTY LINE
        if (paragraph num_line of text_data) ≠ "" then
            set the_offset to (offset of (paragraph num_line of text_data) in text_data) - 1
            set remaining_data to (the_data) & (text the_offset thru -1) of text_data
            set eof of file_id to the_offset
        else -- LINE IS EMPTY
            set num_line to num_line - 1
            set the_count to (count of (characters of (paragraph num_line of text_data))) - 1
            set the_offset to (offset of (paragraph num_line of text_data) in text_data) + the_count + 2
            set remaining_data to the_data & linefeed & ((text (the_offset + 1) thru -1) of text_data)
            set eof of file_id to the_offset - 1
        end if

        -- WRITE DATA TO FILE
        --write the_data to file_id -- INSERT LINE
        write remaining_data to file_id -- WRITE REMAINING DATA
        close access file_id
    on error
        try
            close access the_file
        end try
    end try
end InsertLine
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way, but this will accomplish what you're looking for.  Works for me on latest version of Sierra

```
tell application "TextEdit" to make new paragraph at after third paragraph of text of document 1 with data "This is the newcomer sentence. \n"
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER: OPTION 2**
*This Would Be My Choice.*

```
property theFile : POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "test.txt"
property newContent : missing value
property sedSTDOUT : "sed " -- This Option For Testing
property sedOverwriteFile : "sed -i ' ' " -- This Option Overwrites The File

addNewSentence(sedSTDOUT, "sentence C.", "This is the newcomer sentence.")
--addNewSentence(sedOverwriteFile, "sentence C.", "This is the newcomer sentence.") -- Writes To The File

to addNewSentence(whichSED, lastTextItemsOfSentenceToAddNewSentenceAfter, newSentenceContent)
    set newContent to do shell script whichSED & "'s/" & lastTextItemsOfSentenceToAddNewSentenceAfter & ¬
        "/" & lastTextItemsOfSentenceToAddNewSentenceAfter & "\\" & linefeed & ¬
        newSentenceContent & "/' " & quoted form of theFile
    return newContent
end addNewSentence
```

Comment: When testing this, I only had one document open in textedit therefore "document 1" worked. If you have several documents open, you may need to tweak the code a little bit so it targets the correct document.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to write to the text file **without opening** the file. The file will never be open when the script is run. Hence, I am looking for a more "behind the scenes" method.